# Form with Site Content that Creates an Entity with User Created Content and Site Content Combined

Tags: entities

Webform and EntityForm do not seem to have the ability to create entities.

Please help me find modules that can be used to build a Planning Form that creates User Created Planning Entities for the use case below. Any further tips or modules for the bonus features would also be greatly appreciated.

**Minimally Viable Product:**

At its core this is a way for Authenticated Users to plan for a conference. The user views videos, pictures and text then saves notes about the videos, pictures and text, and later accesses an entity they created with the original videos, pictures and text grouped with their user created content. So a video about networking at a conference has a form below it for the user to make notes they can see later and know it’s notes for that particular video.

**Parameters:**

- Three Entity Types:

  1. Conference Node  Content Type (that provides access to the Conference Planning Form)
  2. Conference Planning Form (for viewing standard Drupal Fields and saving user created content)
  3. User Created Conference Planning Entity (for future viewing and editing of Conference Planning Form site admin and user created content)
- The user does not need to actually book the event through this feature. This feature is to help them stay organized.
- If there is a way to have the user save their User Created Conference Planning Entity on the front end that would be great but not required.

**Use Case:**

1. User finds a Conference Node they are interested in.

   1. User selects a button to plan for the conference and they are taken to a standard site wide Conference Planning Form.
2. The Conference Planning Form (hopefully an entity) contains instructions and tips created by the site admin (such as videos, pictures, links or text), and a form field the authenticated user can use to create notes (links and text) grouped with the field or a group of fields the site admin created  that display on the Conference Planning Form to generate a User Created Conference Planning Entity.

   1. The authenticated user fills out the form fields they would like to use and saves the Conference Planning Form to create a User Created Conference Planning Entity  which is added to their list of User Created Conference Planning Entities.
3. Later the user can access the User Created Conference Planning Entity they created to add content to the form entry fields
4. The user can access the User Created Conference Planning Entity they have created to view notes they created.

**Bonus Features:**

- After saving the Conference Planning Form and when viewing the User Created Conference Planning Entity the user created, the original content from the Conference Planning Form is displayed and grouped with each form field of content the user created the first time they saved Conference Planning Form and created the User Created Conference Planning Entity.
- The ability to for the sited admin to provide site wide generic Conference Planning Form or a custom Conference Planning Form for any Conference Node.
- The ability to automatically displays fields on the Conference Planning Form referencing the Conference Node the user came from with the referenced fields (possibly with Entity Reference module) grouped (possibly using Field Group module) with a form field the user could add notes to.
- A site admin created task list that can be on the Conference Planning Form that would also show on the User Created Conference Planning Entity that could be checked off (possibly using the Flag Module.
- The authenticated user can create a custom task lists on the User Created Conference Planning Entity that they can checked off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out [Flexiform](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexiform) module. This can be used for adding/editing entities using custom form. It has its own drawbacks though. So far I couldn't find a way to create multi-step form using the Flexiform. The documentation says it is WIP. Not sure if it is available now.

[Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2082675) is the article with the comparison on multiple form modules.

Comment: Please mark the response as answered if you are happy with it.